# iPhoto 09 hangs on startup

Tags: macos, iphoto

Every time I run iPhoto 09 on snow leopard it hangs after displaying the main window. The "beach ball" goes on forever and I have to force quit.

Anybody knows what might be going on?

Comment: Disconnecting the iphone, running again, reboting...

Comment: Can you try launching with the *option* key pressed and see if you can select/create another library?

Comment: You can also try moving the file `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iPhoto.plist` temporarily to the desktop. This causes iPhoto to reset to default preferences.

Answer (score 3):

Same problem here, but not able to sort it out yet. Mine happened after accidentally interrupting an import from my iPhone.

Possible solutions:

- [Repair disk permissions](http://discussions.info.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=7818612) using Disk Utility
- Delete iPhoto Caches from `~/Library/Caches/com.Apple.iphoto`
- Delete preference file (as above) from `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iPhoto.plist`
- Restart iPhoto with cmd and alt held down, and rebuild library, databases, thumbnails etc, or [restore from the automatic backup](http://discussions.info.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2791252&tstart=0).
- Use [iPhoto Library Manager](http://fatcatsoftware.com/iplm) to [rebuild library](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=12663645)
- Hold down alt as you start iPhoto, and create a new clean library

None of these have so far worked for me: iPhoto starts up, seems fine (displays all of my images) but beachballs as soon as I click in the photo library pane, or try and import an image in to a clean library.

Other possible solutions I've seen mentioned.

- Create a clean user account and see if you still have problems after importing the library.
- [Turn off](http://discussions.info.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=5109008) the [Photo library](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=509593) [sharing options](https://discussions.apple.com/message/9773910#9773910) in iPhoto preferences (I can't do this as my hang prevents me accessing this)
- [Clean reinstall](http://discussions.info.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2800301&tstart=0) of iPhoto
- [Possible issues with external disks](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1974854) (depending on partition table format)
- Possible issues with [faces scans](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1969073&tstart=0).

I am on 10.6.6 / iPhoto 9.1.1 (= iPhoto '11) - around 10k images in the library.

Sources of information are linked, but arg, can only post two, so will add follow up comments with additional ones.

Comment: I edited your post to include reference URLs. [7] and [9] are identical, is that correct?

Comment: Yup - when I wrote this, I couldn't find a way to link to specific comments in the thread on the apple site. Looks like that's fixed now, will edit link 7